# How to export Test Cases with all the steps assigned to a test case in?

Tags: plugins, tfs

I have a project that contains different Work Items types. I would like to export the Test Cases but I would also like to see all steps of the test case in nice visual way. In some example I have up to 3 - 4 steps for a test case.

Currently, I can export them, but they are not displayed properly. 
To give you a clear example, what I have for a test case in my Excel File is this:

Open test book

Test book opens in Editor

Modify the book by adding a topic

Topic added to book in book structure

Save the book and close it

Book saved with added topic appearing when opening it again.

What I would like to have is this: 
1. Open test book
2. Test book opens in Editor
3. Topic added to book in book structure
4. Book saved with added topic appearing when opening it again.

I can perform the modification of the file manually, but it will take too long time.

Any idea on how I can do this ?

Comment: I actually forgot to mention, but the project does not have any test plans.

Comment: So do you want to the numbers? How you currently export the test case? there is a few options.

Comment: I am currently using the TFS Plug In to export all Test Cases. But, as I mentioned above, the steps for each test case are not clearly sorted out. I see them all in a raw, with a delimitation. But I would like to have them as a list. I can not add files here cause I would share with you. What are your options to obtain what I want ?